# MongoDB read document with an embedded document - c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I successfully inserted a document using the following code:

```
 public async Task<List<Book>> ListBooks(BooksSearchFilter booksSearchFilter)
        {

    _client = new MongoClient(); //ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoConnection"]
    _db = _client.GetDatabase(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDatabaseName"]);

    var collection = _db.GetCollection<Book>("book");

    Publisher p = new Publisher { 
        Name = "O'Reilly Media", 
        Founded = 1980, 
        Location = "CA" };
    Book bookTest = new Book { 
        Language = "English", 
        Pages = 68, 
        PublishedDate = DateTime.Now, 
        Publisher = p, 
        Title = "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide" };
    bookTest.Author = new List<string>();
    bookTest.Author.Add("auth1");
    await collection.InsertOneAsync(bookTest);

    var books = await collection.Find(b => b.Language =="English").ToListAsync();
}
```

But when i tried to read a record using the following code it returns an empty list:

```
var books = await collection.Find(b => b.Language == "English").ToListAsync();
```

Please note that when i press F10 to step over this line in debugger the cursor disappear and Fiddler shows empty results, Do I miss something?

The entities I used:

```
public class Book
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string  Id { get; set; }

    //[BsonElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    //[BsonElement("author")]
    public List<string> Author { get; set; }

    //[BsonElement("published_date")]
    public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }

    //[BsonElement("pages")]
    public double Pages { get; set; }

    //[BsonElement("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    //[BsonElement("publisher")]
    public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }

}

public class Publisher
{
    //[BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //[BsonElement("founded")]
    public double Founded { get; set; }

    //[BsonElement("location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using 'Where' instead of 'Find'?

Comment: No such method in collection class, i'm using the latest c# driver version 2.0. All methods are now asynchronous.

Comment: - Could you post the contents of the book collection from the shell? db.book.find().pretty()?
- Fiddler is an HTTP sniffer. MongoDB doesn't use HTTP, but rather TCP. Fiddler will never see any MongoDB traffic.

Comment: yes db.book.find().pretty() returned results, I think the problem is because the above code is inside a method that is marked async, may be it returns the control to the caller (Web API) before finishing the fetching task.  public async Task<List<Book>> ListBooks(BooksSearchFilter booksSearchFilter)
        {<<The above code>>}

Comment: If `books` is already a list, then the call has returned. The list isn't lazily populated (unlike the `IAsyncCursor`), so once you have the list it can't have anything to do with the asynchrony of the call. Do you actually get to the point where you can inspect the list? Enable query logging (through the integrated profiler) in mongodb to see if the query is received by the server and contains what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to reproduce what you are describing, but when I use F10 to step over this line of code:

```
var books = await collection.Find(b => b.Language == "English").ToListAsync();
```

the result is that the value of the books variable is a List with one element in it, just as expected.

Fiddler wouldn't show anything anyway, because it monitors HTTP traffic and the protocol between a MongoDB driver and the server is a binary protocol over a TCP socket.